# Как ограничить пространство на рабочем столе для определенной программы?

Tags: windows-8, desktop

Имеется рабочее окно программы, например `Eclipse IDE`. Необходимо заставить программу "думать" что она разворачивается на весь экран при клике на кнопке **развернуть**, но при этом окно будет разворачиваться не на весь экран 27" монитора, а например по высоте оно будет разворачиваться максимально, а по ширине например по определенному размеру. Может есть какие то готовые решения?

Comment: А разве окно программы "не вспоминает" свое предыдущее положение и размер?

Comment: В том то все и дело что нет, иногда ширину и отступы по бокам запонимает но высоту сбрасывает. Например так делает Google Chrome

Comment: Посмотрите на эти утилиты: [TaskLayout](http://www.systemgoods.com/) и [Windows Layout Manager](http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/)

Comment: @Bulson да спасибо, это то что нужно.